PostgreSQL: What are different operations make the use of Temp files?
We have time series monitoring on both pg_stat_database as well as pg_stat_statements. Recently We have been observing temp file usage in our DB during certain period. But for the same period we are not able to find queries that in total equates to total usage from pg_stat_database. We have seen somewhere maintenance operations like vacuuming and analyse can cause temp file usage, but for the period we couldn't find such activities as well.  Is there any other internal operations which can cause temp file usage?

Which columns are comparing between those two views?

@jjanes temp_blks_read/temp_blks_written from pg_stat_statements temp_bytes from pg_stat_database.

VACUUM and ANALYZE shouldn't create temporary files.
First of all, the statistics from pg_stat_database need not be 100% accurate. Second, pg_stat_database.temp_bytes measures the size of temporary files in bytes, which pg_stat_statement.temp_blks_read measures how many 8kB blocks were read, and pg_stat_statement.temp_blks_written measures the 8kB blocks written.
A temporary file can be read more than once, so what I would compare is the sum of pg_stat_statement.temp_blks_written and pg_stat_database.temp_bytes. The latter should be about 8192 times the former.
If you detect a notable difference, perhaps you don't collect statistics for all statements. Set pg_stat_activity.track to all, so that pg_stat_statements also gathers statistics for statements that were not sent by the client, such as statements inside database functions or procedures and statements issued by a trigger.

I hv mentioned about time series gathering on pg_stat_statements, but i am unable to find queries that using temp bytes during that period.

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have changed the answer.

FYI, we are using pgwatch2 with grafana, i believe you are part of dev team? From the SQL code i can see that the tool is converting pages into bytes and if it's a problem with reading same file multiple times at least i could be able to find some queries during the period which may or may not be equal to temp_bytes. But in this case no queries at all.

Can you explain what exactly you mean with "But in this case no queries at all"? If words fail, perhaps some SQL can help.

i mean for an instance where i see nearly 6GB temp_bytes from pg_stat_database for a period, for the same period i am not able to find any queries at all which using temp_bytes from pg_stat_statements.

Did you set pg_stat_statements.track = all?

it's set to 'top' means am i missing some statements?

Yes, that means that you are missing some statements.

Great, thanks very much for the help
